# Magento CSS load order

Tags: magento2

[image]

Open any web page, before a second is abnormal, is it OK to wait for a while. How can I solve it ?

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It's look like. You must have critical css path is enabled.

Please go to below configuration and set "No".

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> CSS Setting -> Use CSS critical path = No
```

hope this helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

Using the view source(ctrl+U) of webpage option you will see some css file names after clicking on them are you able to open them ? You will found some path mis-match there. 
Please try this, go to your terminal in Ubuntu then reach the place where the solution is installed then run the command `bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0` 
After then run command `bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f`
It will start work after then.

If after hard refresh still problem persists then try to run command setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy -f then give permissions to var and pub as  `chmod 777 -R var pub` then run command `bin/magento c:c && bin/magento c:f` and do the hard refresh in chrome browser. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using client-side less compilation. Try with server-side less compilation in the below configuration.

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Frontend development workflow

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I needed